# How do I use Coffeescript with Ember App Kit?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I am trying to use Coffeescript with ember app kit but it's blowing up when I rename router.js to router.coffee. I am assuming it has to do something with the emc6 module syntax. How do I properly convert it?

```
Router = Ember.Router.extend()
Router.map ->
  @route "component-test"
  @route "helper-test"

export default Router
```

Comment: have a look in the Gruntfile.js at this line: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L6

Comment: I ran that but that file still blows up

Comment: router appears to be the one thing that doesn't work. You can create other .coffee files and they work fine.

Answer (score 5):

As CoffeScript currently can't parse ES6 module syntax, wrap your `import`/`export` statements with backticks:

```
`export default Router`
```

Hopefully that alone will get it working for you.